# which clustering algorithm is more likely to give the expected clustering result

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am given a set of 2-dimentional data in the format of Figure 1. The layout and the expected clustering results (in two different colors and symbols) are shown in Figure 2. **Among the common clustering methods, which one(s) is/are more likely to give the expected clustering result? Why?** Thanks.

```
 Figure 1
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
 Figure 2
```

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather vague. So what exactly do you mean by among "the clustering approaches"?

I'll give it a try anyway:

At first glance I would guess, that there are a lot of good clustering algorithms which wouldn't have a hard time clustering your data, for the obvious reason, that your **data is well separated**.

Another thing to keep in mind is, whether you know the **amount of clusters** your expecting in your data, which you don't really state, but which highly influences the approach you would want to take (or whether you would add some sort of metric which determines the quality of clustering in order to find the suitable amount of clusters e.g. Ellbow method, or some entropy measurement).

Following a few clustering approaches that could work for you:

- k-means
- Region growing

I hope this gives you a start what to look into.